# How can I covert all property to all optional in a type?

Tags: typescript

I have a type like:

```js
type A1 = {
 x: string,
 y: string
}
```

and I would like to convert it to

```
type A2 = {
 x?: string,
 y?: string
}
```

I have searched similar problems but could not find a good way to simply achieve this goal. Can somebody solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: `type PartialA1 = Partial<A1>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype):

It constructs a type with all properties of Type set to optional.

```
type A1 = {
 x: string,
 y: string
}

type A2 = Partial<A1>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggjFAvFA3gKCgDwFxQM7ABOAlgHYDmANBiLgSRWgL5pqiSwBMSUACgIaFgxfgBsAPPAB8AbjRA)